# Dispatch event when you click in legend of pieChart nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

how can I dispatch event when I click in legend of pieChart nvd3 and get the values ​​of the series (visible or not visible)?

Answer (score 3):

if you have:

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
```

This is the way to capture the event:

```
chart.dispatch.on ('stateChange', function (e) {myFunction (e)});
```

after:

```
function myFunction (e) {
    var series = e.disabled; 
    //series is array with "true" or "false" value, this values
    //depending if the serie[i] is showing

    //more code here for processing
};
```

Comment: Go ahead and accept your own answer. It worked for me, too.